# What's the meaning and structure of this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis

[image]

In the last sentence, I don't understand this meaning and structure 'They might, but who, bar a tiny majority, would want to hear the answers'.

Could you expain this? Thanks!

Comment: You should type it out carefully.  It might make more sense, and can more easily be quoted or looked up.

Comment: It means that the writer is a male chauvinist porcine.

Comment: I don't think so--I think it's sarcasm.  "Only a tiny majority" would want to hear the answers.

Comment: @Xanne Thanks! but I could understand if the explanation of structure is added. 'bar' is omitted.

Comment: "bar" means "except" here.  "tiny majority" refers to women, who are just over 50% of the population

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP asks for an explanation of the following, apparently from a book, noting that women might ask different questions of political candidates different from those men would ask.

> "They might, but who, bar a tiny majority, would want to hear the
>   answers?"

They (women) might (ask different questions), but who, bar [except] a tiny majority [a little over half of the population--that is, women], would want to hear the answers?

"bar" is a preposition; its object is "a tiny majority"

This is sarcasm--at least as far as I can tell from the short excerpt. The paragraphs above, in the photo, may also be sarcastic; more context would be needed to figure out the views of the author.